# test case hanging at start_item

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've been facing a problem with start_item. Every time it gets to `start_item`, my entire test hangs and there's no way I can find out what the issue is. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
task good_bad_seq_0_task ();
  RX_eth10g req;
  RX_eth10g rsp;
  RX_eth10g_knobs t;
  int good_bad_seq_count;
  //'Vy_good_bad_long_seq' is a loop Variable
  int Vy_good_bad_long_seq;
  int tmp_rand_status;
  tmp_rand_status = std::randomize (good_bad_seq_count) with { 
    good_bad_seq_count inside {100};
  };
  if(!tmp_rand_status) begin
    `uvm_error(get_full_name(), "Randomization failed!");
  end
  `uvm_info(get_full_name(), $sformatf(": Driving good_bad_long_seq %0d times ...",good_bad_seq_count), UVM_HIGH)
  for(Vy_good_bad_long_seq = 0; Vy_good_bad_long_seq < good_bad_seq_count; Vy_good_bad_long_seq++) begin
    req = new();
    start_item (req);     // Nothing after this is executed
    t = good_bad_seq_knob;
    req.set_seqitem_type (t);
    if(!req.randomize ()) begin
      `uvm_error("RAND_FAILED", $psprintf("Randomization failed : %s",req.get_full_name()));
    end
    finish_item (req);
    get_response (rsp);
  end
  `uvm_info(get_full_name(), $sformatf(": Completed %0d times ...",good_bad_seq_count), UVM_HIGH)
endtask: good_bad_seq_0_task
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My guess is there is an infinite loop inside `start_item`.  Can you show us the code? Suggestion: add `uvm_info` or `$display` messages to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The `start_item(...)` task will unblock once the driver connected to the item's parent sequencer calls `get_next_item(...)`. You'll need to check your driver implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`req` has not been given a parent sequencer. See the documentation for `create_item(...)` in `uvm_sequence_base`. As Tudor mentioned `get_next_item(...)` also needs to be called on the parent sequencer's seq_item_export.